# Complex Grid in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, telerik

I need to display data in WinForms in a very complex way.

There are many rows, and each row needs to be displayed slightly different.
Each row's model has a list of entities inside it, each translated to a button.

The buttons for each row are presnted in specific way according to some rules. Each row has different amount of buttons displayed in a different way in rows and cols.

On top of that, the display needs to be binded to the model and listen for many frequent changes, not only for value changes to display but also calculated data that indicates things like if to display the row or not, or to display the button or not, color indicators and more.

Now it is implemented with Telerik GridView, and, as you might expect, it doesn't function very well, too much data. The scroll bar is faltering, on many occations the rows or cells are not displayed until the user scrolls a bit.

This is an example of how I would like it to be displayed (without colors and stuff)

[image: Example]

This is a very short sample of the code:

```
public class CustomCellElement : GridDataCellElement
{
    protected override SizeF ArrangeOverride(SizeF finalSize)
    {
        try
        {
            float x = finalSize.Width;
            float y = 0;
            float maxHeight = 0;

                foreach (var child in this.Children.ToList())
                {
                    try
                    {                            
                       var element = child as RadButtonElement;
                       arrange logic...
                       child.Arrange(location);
                       .
                       .

    ------------            

    protected override void CreateChildElements()
    {
        _childItems = new ThreadSafedBindingList<E>();
        _childItemsBindings = new List<Binding>();
        base.CreateChildElements();
    }

    protected override void SetContentCore(object value)
    {
        ...
        foreach (var someChild in childs.ToList())
        {
             AddItem(someChild);
        }
        ...
    ....

    protected override void SetBindings(SomeChildEntity childElement, CustomRadButtonElement item)
    {
        ....
        Creating many bindings necessary for each SomeChildEntity 
        ....
    }


....
```

I will be very glad to hear suggestions !

Thanks

Comment: a screenshot of what you already did (GridView) or some code of your data model would be helpful for us to understand your question.

Comment: You can implement this in 15 minutes in WPF, using built-in support for UI virtualization, making it blazingly fast. Simply put an `ElementHost` in your existing winforms app and do this particular UI in WPF. winforms doesn't support anything complex.

Comment: Actualy this is what I'm trying now, does it have a down side?
From my exprience loading ElementHost for WPF is taking a long time in the initial load

Comment: @GuyLevin there's probably going to be a delay while the CLR loads the WPF assemblies the first time. You can mitigate that by early loading them (making references to WPF classes early in your application code).

Comment: Can you share the example you have right now with the Telerik grid. I don't think there should be an issue with the scroll.

Comment: I'll try, its a bit long code with custom cells.
I'm building and aranging the buttons inside a custom cell according to its values, will edit the post

Comment: You can upload it somewhere and post the link.

Comment: Edited the post with a short sample code for the problematic custom cell. Hope its enough, tell me if not.

Comment: If you upload working sample somewhere I will have a look at it, but from the code provided it will take quite a while to get it working and it will not be the same case as yours.